# Website under IIS 7.5 with Application Pool giving Server Error

Tags: web-applications, iis-7.5

I created a new application pool in IIS 7.5 and chose ApplicationPoolIdentity for Identity.

When I assign a website to use this app pool, I get a 500 server error. I have other websites using application pool with same Identity and asp.net runtime and get no error.

I changed Identity on the pool to NetworkService, LocalService, LocalSystem and still get the same error.

Why am I getting this error, and how can I overcome this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the website code the same? The 500 Internal error is not always related to IIS problems.

Comment: yes, the content is the same. I only change the application pool that the website uses and I get or not get the error based on which pool is used.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you posted the error you are getting.  If you have other applications using this app pool, and they are working, then I would be suspect of the application, or the applications dependencies/references.  If this is coming from a previous version of iis that ran in 32 bit mode, you may need to enable 32 bit mode in the application pools advanced options.  Post the text from the exception and we could provide more precise troubleshooting steps.

Comment: 500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

No other applications are using the pool. This is a new pool I just created and assigned to one website. This is on a new windows 2008 r2 server, so no previous history or 32bit apps.

Comment: Browse to the page locally, while logged on to the web server itself, and display the error.